# Imbalanced Data for Random ferns

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

For a Multiclass problem, should the data be balanced for machine learning algorithms such as Random forests and Random ferns or is it ok for it to be imbalanced for a certain extent?

Comment: I'd migrate it to: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The issue with imbalanced classes raises when the disproportion alters the *separability* of the classes instances. But this does not happen in ever imbalanced dataset: sometimes the more data you have from one class the better you can differentiate the scarse data from it since it lets you find more easily which features are meaningful to create an discriminating plane (even though you are not using discriminative analysis the point is to classify-separate the instances according to classes).

For example I can remember the [KDDCup2004](http://osmot.cs.cornell.edu/kddcup/tasks.html) protein classification task in which one class had 99.1% of the instances in the training set but if you tried to use under sampling methods to alleviate the imbalance you would only get worse results. That meaning that the large amount of data from the first class defined the data in the smaller one.

Concerning random forests, and decision trees in general, they work by selecting, at each step, the most promising feature that can partitionate the set into two (or more) class-meaningful subsets. Having inherently more data about one class does not bias this partitioning by default ( = always) but only when the imbalance is not representative of the classes real distributions.

So I suggest that you first run a multivariate analysis to try to get the extent of imbalance among classes in your dataset and the run a series of experiments with different undersampling ratios if you still ar ein doubt.

Comment: What about Random ferns?Can it be a general case that we can accept the data imbalance for other algorithms if it is representative for the classes' real distributions as you said?

Comment: Even ferns follow this rule since if the instances are separable an optimal bayes classifier would certainly separate them correctly. A naive bayes or a random ferns classifier would resent more from the lack of independence from attributes but if it is not related to the class imbalance it shall not degrade your performance. As I said, try to run it with several sets for undersampling, incrementally increasing the ratio of the classes until you reach the 1:1:1 ... :1 ratio

Answer (score 0):

I have used Random Forrests in my task before. Although  the data don't need be balanced, however if the positive samples are too few, the pattern of the data maybe drown in the noise. Most of classify methods even (random forrests and ada boost) should have this flaw more or less.'Over sample' may be a good idea to deal with this problem.

Perhaps the paper [Logistic Regression in rare](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=logistic%20regrssion%20in%20rare&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://gking.harvard.edu/files/0s.pdf&ei=ITT3UZiRO8SmlQWl1oDIBg&usg=AFQjCNEWxPJzCCtxnG323SWS2sRyV_tu1w)is useful with this sort of problem, although its topic is logistic regression.